# C# windows forms TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, tabcontrol

I have a Windows forms application with a `TabControl` with 2 tabs. `tab1` does some calculations and `tab2` has a chart that graphs updated values from `tab1`.

The issue is that I cannot click `tab2` while `tab1` processing are running. I want to be able to see the graph change in real-time but I have to wait until processes in `tab1` are complete before I can click `tab2`, otherwise my app will lock.

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` for the graph.

Any advice?

Comment: If I place the chart on tab1 it works just fine.

Comment: Yes. Do the calculation in an async manner. Winforms have a control called BackgroundWorker, That's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you have to remember that both DoWork and WorkCompleted background worker event handlers are executed in the nonGUI thread so you must to sync to GUI thread when accessing form controls. This can be done using `Control.InvokeRequired` and  `Control.Invoke()`

Comment: Chart is a fairly dangerous control, it won't throw an InvalidOperationException when you update its properties from a worker thread.  Even though that is illegal, deadlock is one of the side-effects.   So you have to get this right without such help, you can do the "calculation" in a worker but the chart must be updated from the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll start looking into BackgroundWorker